# Calculating week start/end dates for the next X weeks

Tags: php, date, time

I am trying to build a function in PHP that, depending on the date will give me

The current week (mon-sun) 20/8/12 to 26/8/12

Following week+1 (mon-sun) 27/8/12 to 02/9/12

Following week+2 (mon-sun) 03/9/12 to 09/9/12

Following week+3 (mon-sun)

Following week+4 (mon-sun)

Following week+5 (mon-sun)

I have tried using the following, but is there anything cleaner??

```
$week0_mon = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y").'W'.date('W')."1"));
$week0_sun = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y").'W'.date('W')."7"));

$week1_mon = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($week0_mon)) . " +1 week"));
$week1_sun = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($week0_sun)) . " +1 week"));

echo $week0_mon.' to '.$week0_sun.'<br />';
echo $week1_mon.' to '.$week1_sun.'<br />';
```

Comment: date('N', $timestamp); will give you the weekday number mon-sun (1-7). So if you strtotime('-'.(date('N', $timestamp)-1).' days', $timestamp); it will move the timestamp back to monday.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it like this. I'm not sure if it is exactly what you want.

```
function plus_week($addWeek){
    $date = date("d.m.Y",time());
    $newdate = strtotime ( '+'.$addWeek.' week' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
    $newdate = date ( 'd/m/y' , $newdate );
    return $newdate;
}

for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++){
    echo "Following week+".$i." ".plus_week($i)." to ".plus_week($i+1)."<br/>";
}
```

From this you will get answer like this:

Following week+1 29/08/12 to 05/09/12

Following week+2 05/09/12 to 12/09/12

Following week+3 12/09/12 to 19/09/12

Following week+4 19/09/12 to 26/09/12

Following week+5 26/09/12 to 03/10/12

Following week+6 03/10/12 to 10/10/12

Comment: this will give ranges of current date, you need to -date('N',$timestamp)+1 to remove the weekday number +1 to get back to monday. And range need to be +week to +week-1 (mon-sun) not (mon-mon)

Comment: sorry that should be -1 not +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will answer to your issue, it calculates the previous monday and start from here to add one week at a time. Just edit the `for`

```
$dOffsets = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");
$prevMonday = mktime(0,0,0, date("m"), date("d")-array_search(date("l"),$dOffsets), date("Y"));
$oneWeek = 3600*24*7;$toSunday = 3600*24*6;

for ($i=0;$i<= 5;$i++)
{
    echo "Week +",$i," (mon-sun) ",
            date("d/m/Y",$prevMonday + $oneWeek*$i)," to ",
            date("d/m/Y",$prevMonday + $oneWeek*$i + $toSunday),"<br>";
}
```

This gives me

```
Week +0 (mon-sun) 20/08/2012 to 26/08/2012
Week +1 (mon-sun) 27/08/2012 to 02/09/2012
Week +2 (mon-sun) 03/09/2012 to 09/09/2012
Week +3 (mon-sun) 10/09/2012 to 16/09/2012
Week +4 (mon-sun) 17/09/2012 to 23/09/2012
Week +5 (mon-sun) 24/09/2012 to 30/09/2012
```

Comment: +1 I like this as you can change it calculate any day of the week as your start day. ie Wed-Tues

Comment: will this work when current date is at the start of the month (after monday) as day could then be negative?

Comment: This works at any time, even with negative day (Ex Sunday at beggining of a month) Since `mktime()` does the work

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted @Wr1t3r answer to give correct date ranges as follows:

```
function plus_week($addWeek=0){
    $last_monday_timestamp=strtotime('-'.(date('N')-1).' days');
    if($addWeek!=0){
        if($addWeek>0) $addWeek='+'.$addWeek;
        $last_monday_timestamp=strtotime($addWeek.' week', $last_monday_timestamp);
    }
    $end_week_timestamp = strtotime ('+6 days', $last_monday_timestamp);
    return date('d/m/y', $last_monday_timestamp).' to '.date('d/m/y', $end_week_timestamp);
}
```

date('N') will give weekday number mon-sun (1-7) so if we subtract 1 from this we know how many days to go back to last monday. OR we could have used strtotime('last monday').
BUT this way ensures we dont go back to last monday if we are currently on monday.

Monday=1 so (1-1=0) -0 days = today
Friday=5 so (5-1=4) -4 days = monday
SUNDAY=7 (not 0 if we used 'w') so (7-1=6) -6 days = monday (not tomorrow)

I've also adjusted this to do negative week numbers too.